# Serializing wordpress wp_posts for ajax search, post_content = null

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

```
<?php

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Content-type: application/json'); 

if((@$_GET['query']))
{

$query = @$_GET['query'];

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'johan', 'johan', 'fysiosteo');
$myArray = array();
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, post_name FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type =  'page' AND post_content like '%" . $query . "%'")) {
    $tempArray = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
            $tempArray = $row;
            array_push($myArray, $tempArray);
        }
    echo json_encode($myArray);
}

$result->close();
$mysqli->close();
}

?>
```

Here is my service.php file. When i run this query in phpmyadmin, i get the results i want. But when i call it from another page using an ajax call, the pages content, post_content, gets the value null instead of the text on the page. Is it because of the html tags? Or what might be causing this? Thanks

Comment: This is very dangerous syntax, anyone can insert arbitrary SQL to execute inside of your database. Also, what happens when you echo your query variable? Does anything show up?

Comment: Nice of you to point it out, but wouldn't you do better to elaborate on it for him. Like taking your car to a mechanic and him just saying, "Yep your car is totally messed up, good day sir."

Comment: @Vibhu i know about http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php, i didnt get to that part yet. And yes, the query variable is there.

Comment: Nice of you to point that out Brad, but wouldn't you do better answering the question yourself instead of criticizing someone else? It's like going into a car mechanic and having one of the other customers saying, "I'm sorry your car is broken, but I think you really ought to get a different one, that one is a piece of junk."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was encoding-related. UTF8 solved it.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) {
```

You are currently getting an object.

Comment: `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in...`